# Querying through several models in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have several Models:

```
Workspace
User
Asset
WorkspaceUser
WorkspaceAsset
```

Workspace has many users and assets, through the two join tables (WorkspaceUser, WorkspaceAsset)

I'm trying to find the most efficient and elegant way to find out if there exists a path between a User and an Asset, ie User -> WorkspaceUser -> Workspace -> WorkspaceAsset -> Asset

This is what I have so far:

```
Workspace.joins(:workspace_assets, :workspace_users).where("workspace_assets.asset_id = ? & workspace_users.user_id = ?", assetID, userID)
```

Was hoping for a better solution and perhaps one that would return the asset in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Asset.joins(:workspace_assets => {:workspace => :workspace_users}.
 where("assets.id = ? & workspace_users.user_id = ?", assetID, userID)
```

Comment: You could go one step further by making it a scope in the Asset model, too.